# Readfile max and min number

Tags: java, max, min, readfile

I really need help with a problem I'm working on. I'm trying to find the max and min number in a .txt file that can be any number it just needs to read the file and then print out the max and min numbers. The readfile is working fine, only problem is I only get 0's back for the answer.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class LargeSmall
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      //gets filename
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
      String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

      //opens file
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      //place holders for varibales
      int val = 0;
      int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      //to read all lines of file
      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         //gets min and max number
         int number = inputFile.nextInt();

         if ( val > max)
         {
         max = val;
         }

         if ( val < min)
         {
         min = val;
         }
      }
   //Close file
   inputFile.close();

   //Print out lowest value in the list and highest
   System.out.println("Min number is: " +min);
   System.out.println("Max number is: " +max);                   
   }
}
```

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong, any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the number from the file but after that you never use it again.

```
     int number = inputFile.nextInt();

     if ( number > max)
     {
         max = number ;
     }
     if ( number < min)
     {
         min = number ;
     }
```

Or instead of changing val to number, change the line:

```
int number = inputFile.nextInt();
```

to

```
val = inputFile.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = inputFile.nextInt();
```

instead of

```
int number = inputFile.nextInt();
```

because you read the every line and assign it to the new variable named as number. But you are checking with the val variable. So it gives the result 0.